# I don't know why the file won't open

Tags: c, image-processing, ppm

This is my code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS    
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

typedef struct {    
    int M,N;    
    int min,max;    
    int width;    
    int height;    
    unsigned char **pixels;    
}PPMIMG;
    
int fnReadPPM(char* fileNm,PPMIMG* img);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{    
    PPMIMG img;        

    if(fnReadPPM(argv[1], &img) != FALSE)
    {    
        return TRUE;    
    }

    return  0;
}

int fnReadPPM(char* fileNm ,PPMIMG* img)
{    
    FILE* fp;    
    fp = fopen("/users/ashton/Downloads/test.txt","rb");
    
    if(fileNm == NULL){    
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to File ! : %s\n",fileNm);    
        return FALSE;    
    }
    
    fclose(fp);    
    return TRUE;
}

int fnWritePPM(char* fileNm, PPMIMG* img)
{    
    FILE *fp =fopen(fileNm, "w");    
    if(fp == NULL)
    {    
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create the file.");    
        return FALSE;    
    }        
    return TRUE;
}
```

This is the error code:

```
Unable to File ! : (null)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Check the `errno` value, or just use the [`perror`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/perror) function.

Comment: Actually, it seems that this particular error message is not caused by the file opening per se, but that the `fileNm` is not provided from the command line.

Comment: Don't put a blanc line between each and every line of your code. It makes it less readable and readable code is very important, especially for the one who writes it.

Comment: Use `perror()` to know which error you have.

Comment: Then, should I use something other than fileNm?

Comment: I would expect that you use `fileNm` for `fopen` instead of that string literal. In that case you shouls also check `fileNm` for `NULL`. But of course before you put it into `fopen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrongly test the fopen return value:

```
fp = fopen("/users/ashton/Downloads/test.txt","rb");
if (fp == NULL) {    //<===== Was WRONG, you used fileNm instead of fp
    perror("Unable to File");
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot !  instead of fileNm, i use fp,then that code started to build

Answer (score 1):

The problem ist most likely here:

```
int fnReadPPM(char* fileNm ,PPMIMG* img)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("/users/ashton/Downloads/test.txt","rb"); // you assign fp
    
    if (fileNm == NULL){                                // and here you check for fileNm 
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to File ! : %s\n",fileNm);
        return FALSE;
    }    
    ...
```

You want this:

```
int fnReadPPM(char* fileNm ,PPMIMG* img)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("/users/ashton/Downloads/test.txt","rb");
    
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open file %s.\n", fileNm);
        return FALSE;
    }    
    ...
```

However in the `fnWritePPM` function you did it right.

Comment: thanks a lot ! instead of fileNm, i use fp,then that code started to build